# Fiddler copy paste is broken

Tags: fiddler

I have a strange problem in Fiddler that I have been unable to fix by playing around with the various settings and options.

Copy and paste is not working in the Composer - both in the URI, and much much worst, in the Request Body.

This seem like a silly problem, but it has been the source of much grief for me, as I try to use it for testing a REST service I am developing, I have to manually type in EVERYTHING I need, every time. It is getting painful.

Copy/Paste works fine everywhere else on my machine. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Fiddler, to no success.

If you have any idea what this may be happening, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are not using any special tool from Fiddler, just debugging a bit, you could use Wireshark...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you would be having this problem, but a hacky solution would be making an AutoHotkey script. The script would simply be `Send %clipboard%`. This will just take whatever is in your current clipboard and type it out. References here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Comment: Lol, that worked. Copying into fiddler is now a #v operation (windows hot key v). The bizarre bugs that happen to the world.....

Answer (score 0):

This is currently still an issue for the Linux beta..
an easy workaround is to use `[shift]+[insert]`

Comment: This does paste, but the current problem is that the content from Fiddler4-mono is not being copied at all.